# Widen scope of on/off topic consultation

Tags: discussion

An adjacent question on meta is canvassing opinions about what should be on and off topic. A suggestion I made was deleted by moderators, before my accompanying explanation was written.

Suggestion: let's allow all suggestions related to off-topic causes, solutions, and ameliorations.

If the suggestions aren't any good, they won't get any votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion I opened today was not about the reasons or causes for off topic posts. Re-evaluating which topics the community feels should be on or off topic is the specific point of that post. Allowing answers that are not addressing that question takes away from the whole purpose for opening that question for discussion.

Suggesting reasons for why we get off topic posts or how we can reduce off topic posts does not address that question in any way. That is an entirely different question and if you would like to have that discussion, you are free to start it yourself or suggest that someone start such a discussion.

While your suggestion may be entirely valid and a perfectly good discussion to have, it does not fit where you posted it.

Comment: We have different views on this, but let's just close the matter and focus on the good, narrower, question as that's what you prefer.